# Building multimodule assemblies

Tags: c#, makefile, nmake

I am trying to  build a multimodule assembly. I have got 2 files namely Fraction.cs and MyCalc.cs and both in the same namespace and another AssemblyInfo.cs. I dont know how to make a makefile file so I copied one from the book I am following. Here are the contents

```
ASSEMBLY= MySharedAssembly.dll

BIN=.\bin
SRC=.
DEST=.\bin

CSC=csc /nologo /debug+ /d:DEBUG /d:TRACE 

MODULETARGET=/t:module
LIBTARGET=/t:library
EXETARGET=/t:exe

REFERENCES=System.dll

MODULES=$(DEST)\Fraction.dll $(DEST)\MyCalc.dll
METADATA=$(SRC)\Assemblyinfo.cs

all: $(DEST)\MySharedAssembly.dll

# Assembly metadata placed in the same module as manifest
$(DEST)\$(ASSEMBLY): $(METADATA) $(MODULES) $(DEST) $(CSC) $(LIBTARGET) /addmodule:$(MODULES: =;) /out:$@ %s

# Add MyCalc.dll module to this dependency list
$(DEST)\MyCalc.dll: MyCalc.cs $(DEST) $(CSC) $(MODULETARGET) /r:$(REFERENCES: =;) /out:$@ %s

# Add Fraction
$(DEST)\Fraction.dll: Fraction.cs $(DEST) $(CSC) $(MODULETARGET) /r:$(REFERENCES: =;) /out:$@ %s

$(DEST)::
!
if !EXISTS($(DEST))
    mkdir $(DEST)
!endif
```

I understand the whole lot but am not familiar with the syntax. So when I am trying to run nmake I am getting the following error

makefile(21) : fatal error v1033: syntax error:  ':' unexpected

I am assuming something is wrong in line 21. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It finally worked when I copy paseted the code from the Internet. The reason it worked is because the line that has error has been divided into two lines using the return key.

$(DEST)\$(ASSEMBLY): $(METADATA) $(MODULES) $(DEST)
    $(CSC) $(LIBTARGET) /addmodule:$(MODULES: =;) /out:$@ %s

Answer (score 0):

```
$(DEST)::
```

Is this the  faulty line?

Comment: no not this one its the one that starts with $(DEST)\$(ASSEMBLY):

Comment: I have been trying different methods to make it work but to no avail. And then I thought to target the error code instead of the makefile. It says on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42y74zxt.aspx that the error code is U1033 and it occurs when the makefile has been formatted by a word processor. Now I created this file in notepad and possibly it also means the same. I have to try something diffent to recreate the file like on dos prompt using older style line editors like edit.

Comment: nope I have even tried creating the file at cmd prompt with copy con, it still doesn't work!!